# Slick carousel doesnt work on bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, slick.js

Slick carousel not working on bootstrap popover, what will be the way to fix it. Though the slick carousel work when it is out side the bootstrap popover. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dskgsaat/

```
<style>
    .slider-car{ display:none;}
</style>

<div class="container"><h3>Popover Example</h3>
    <a href="#" id ="pop" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" type="button" data-html="true">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 slider-car">
    <div class="cd-hero-slider " id="elem-flav">
        <div id="section-a"> <img src="Flavor.png" alt="..."> </div>
        <div id="section-b"> <img src="Flavor-2.png" alt="..."> </div>
        <div id="section-c"> <img src="Flavor-3.png" alt="..."> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: true,
                content: function() {
                    return $('.slider-car').html();
                },
                template: '<div class="popover my-popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
            });
            $('.cd-hero-slider').slick({
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                dots: true,
                arrows: false
            });
            $('.cd-hero-slider').resize()
        });
    $("#pop").click(function(){
        $("p").show('.slider-car');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why do you have 2 nested script tags?

Comment: Typo there in pasting ! It’s like on same page if you use slick carousel it works ! As soon as it’s on popover you mages won’t move !

Comment: here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dskgsaat/

Answer (score 1):

Slick slider `doesn't get initialized` if the `parent division is hidden`. Attaching `click function to popover` did the job.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {       
    return $('.slider-car').html();
    },
    template: '<div class="popover my-popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
    }).click(function() {
        $('.cd-hero-slider').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 500,
            dots: false,
            arrows: true,
            centerMode:true,
            infinite:true
        });
    });
```

The working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dskgsaat/13/